# TypeError: invalid 'in' operand obj while getting json keys

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kc11/h6nh1gvw/2/

I'm trying to get the keys from a json string, with

```
var keys = $.map(a, function(element,key) { return key; }); .
```

However I am getting:

```
TypeError: invalid 'in' operand obj
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.map()` expects an object or an array, not a string.

It is not clear what result you're trying to achieve in your jsFiddle, but you should not be stringifying your object (e.g. turning it into a JSON string) before passing it to `$.map()`.

Perhaps you just want:

```
var keys = $.map(getCarData()[0], function(element,key) { return key; }); .
```

Comment: The reason for this is I may need to receive and process json from a backend

Comment: @user61629 - `$.map()` requires an object or array, not a string.  Period.  If you get JSON from a backend, then call `JSON.parse()` on it to convert it to an object.

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
var b = getCarData()[0]; 
var keys = $.map(b, function(element,key) { return key; });
```

Instead of the stringified version.